# Using NativeBase textArea in react native

Tags: react-native, native-base

Hi so I want to have a textArea in order to let the user send a review message in my app. So how can I retrieve the message wrote by the user using [this](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#textarea-textbox-headref) component ?

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content padder>
            <Item style = {{ marginBottom: 10}}>
                <Input placeholder="Email" />
            </Item>
            <Form style = {{ marginBottom: 20}}>
                <Textarea rowSpan={3} bordered placeholder="Votre message" />
            </Form>
            <Button success>
                <Text>Envoyer</Text>
            </Button>
        </Content>

      </Container>

    );
  }
```

I want to be able to get the email and the message of the user. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

Native-base inputs are an extension of the react-native TextInput component, that's why you can use the `onChangeText` event.
For your example let's say we have two elements in our state an email and a message. `{email: "", message: ""}`

We need to add an onChangeText event to both the inputs as follows:

```
<Input placeholder="Email" onChangeText={email => this.setState({email: email})} />
```

and

```
 <Textarea rowSpan={3} bordered placeholder="Votre message" onChangeText={message=> this.setState({message: message})} />
```

Now you're able to retrieve the text written by the user using `this.state.email` and `this.state.message`

Please read more about handling text inputs in the official react-native documentation in [React-native TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) and in [Handling Text Input](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input)